# Extracting gz in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a directory structure as follows.

```
- app
  Dockerfile
   - target
     - test_app.tar.gz
```

The extraction of the tar.gz will have the following,

```
- lib
- conf
- bin
```

I would like to extract and add lib/* folder to the docker image.

```
FROM docker.hub.com/alpine/jdk1.8:latest  

RUN mkdir -p /service \
            /service/app_lib \
            /service/lib

COPY target/test_app.tar.gz /service/app_lib/
RUN cd  /service/app_lib/ 
RUN tar -xzf test_app.tar.gz
RUN rm test_app.tar.gz
RUN cd lib
COPY * /service/lib/
RUN rm app_lib
```

Getting the below error with this.

```
Step 5/11 : RUN tar -xzf test_app.tar.gz
 ---> Running in edde27a1cc60
tar (child): test_app.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Not sure what is wrong with this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The effect of the `RUN cd` command only persists for that single line, at the next line, you're back in `/`, so the file can't be found. Use `WORKDIR` instead of `RUN cd ...` and it should work as you expect.
Or you can put the whole thing into a single `RUN` command like

```
RUN cd /service/app_lib/ && tar -xzf test_app.tar.gz && rm test_app.tar.gz
```

Same thing applies for the next `RUN cd lib` part.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir

Comment: See answer from @stacksonstacks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52069435/3553541 for ADD command. No need for COPY > tar -x > rm.

Answer (score 43):

The `ADD` directive will unpack the `.gz` automatically on build

```
ADD target/test_app.tar.gz /service/app_lib
# Clean up
RUN rm -rf /service/app_lib/conf \
           /service/app_lib/bin
```

Comment: That sounds super-cool, but doesn't appear to work for me. Running Docker v18.03.1-ce-mac65 (24312) (on Mac, obv). Looks like I need to un-tar myself.

Comment: @Tom that's reasonably recent Docker version. Check ADD documentation https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add if you're not missing something. Also try verifying <src> path to the tar.gz file and .dockerignore for ignoring files in build context.

Comment: Mac Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962 with a .gz file and it didn't work either

Comment: docs say it will check the file magic number/header _not_ the extension name when deciding whether to unpack or simply `cp` the file. Check it really is a tar'd archive you're testing with

Comment: also note that the automatic unpacking happens only with local .gz files, not files fetched from a remote source. (I was trying to use a github release.)